# menu and submenu in tree structure

Tags: php, laravel

I need to create menu in below json format. Below is my table from which I'm fetching data:-

```
id  title       parent_id   url
5   Dashboard   0           /dashboard 
6   Settings    0           /home 
7   Menu        6           /menu 
8   Menu Assign 6           /menu-assign 
9   Test        5           /test 
10  Demo        9           /demo
```

My expected format is given below.

```
public tail = [
 {
   name: 'Dashboard',
   link: '/dashboard',
   child: [
     {
       name: 'Test',
       link: '/test',
       child: [
         {
           name: 'Demo',
           link: '/demo',
         }
       ]
     },
   ]
 },
 {
   name: 'Settings',
   link: '/settings',
   child: [
     {
       name: 'Menu',
       link: '/menu',
       child: []
     },
     {
       name: 'Menu Assign',
       link: '/menu-assign',
       child: []
     }
   ]
 }
];
```

I have tried the below code

```
public function menuTree($parent=0,$level=0){
        Global $menuArr;
        $menus = Menu::where('parent_id','=',$parent)->get();
        foreach($menus as $allMenu){
            $menuArr[$allMenu->id][$level] = str_repeat("-", $level).$allMenu->title;
            $level++;
            $this->menuTree($allMenu->id,$level);
            $level--;
        }
        return $menuArr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to test this thoroughly. However, you can use the [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) instance to loop through the `menu` items. This will have to be achieved within a few steps.

- Firstly, we will need to create a `$level` public variable, which can be used throughout the controller class. We set this as the beginning of the `menuTree()` method.
- `$this->level = $this->level ?: $level` will check to see if the `$this->level` variable has been set and is greater than `0`. If so, we shall assume that is iterating through the tree, else just set to `0`. This `ternary` expression is the same as `$this->level = $this->level ? $this->level : $level`.
- Moving on, we get all `menus` and use the `map()` collection helper to alter the results we return. This is where we return from a new function called `menuItem()`.
- In `menuItem()` we get the `menu` item's `name` and `link` and add it to a `$data` array.
- We then check if `$this->level` is `true` (if greater than 0). This is done to see if we need to iterate for child menu items. We also check if any `menu` items exist in which are `children` of the current menu item. If both true, we cycle through the process again and reduce the level count by `1`.

To conclude, if `$this->level` is greater than `0`, we return as an `array`, else we return as a `json` array. This is the difference between it completing the tree, and if it is still iterating through a menu level.

Here is the full code.

```
public $level;

public function menuTree($parent = 0, $level = 0)
{
    $this->level = $this->level ?: $level;

    $menus = Menu::where('parent_id', $parent)
        ->get()
        ->map(function ($menu, $key) {
            return $this->menuItem($menu);
        });

    return $this->level ? $menus->toArray() : $menus->toJson();   
}

public function menuItem($item)
{
    $data = [
        'name' => str_slug($item->title),
        'link' => $item->url,
    ];

    if ($this->level && Menu::where('parent_id', $item->id)->count()) {
        $data['child'] = $this->menuTree($item->id);
        $this->level--;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

**Note:** In the event where the `parent_id` is set to `null` instead of `0`, you will need to start the query up differently:

```
...

$menus = Menu::query();

if ($parent) {
    $menus = where('parent_id', $parent);
}

$menus = $menus->get()
    ->map(function ($menu, $key) {
        return $this->menuItem($menu);
    });

...
```

`query()` is used to begin a `eloquent` builder. The condition is set to check if the `parent_id` is not `null|false|0` and apply the query if `true`.